# Karma Unit test not working as intended

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

Once solving one of my errors leads to karma not working as it should do. The down bellow component.spec.ts will generate an error because I haven't imported RouterTestingModule. `Failed: Template parse errors:`

[image]

profile.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';
//import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';


describe('ProfileComponent', () => {
  let component: ProfileComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProfileComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProfileComponent ]
      //,imports: [ RouterTestingModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Once solving the above error, the karma unit test will look like this and not like the first image with failure list etc.

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce it here? https://plnkr.co/edit/G3ihIYvuQ8qFXpUlsBlw?p=preview

Comment: I've added my code, not sure if its righly formatted because I've never used plnkr

Comment: Where is the plunker?

Comment: I don't have rights to save changes

Comment: Use `fork` button

Comment: That should be it, not sure if that is all the required code since I've never used it before

Comment: The error appears to be in `app.component.spec`... and you've posted code for `profile.component.spec`. Have I missed something?